# Need to identify a historical-themed military anime?

Tags: story-identification, anime, medieval

I remember there was this one guy who got assigned to a gate in a high crime area. He set a curfew, disallowing anyone going through the gate.

Some of nobles did not like this guy and purposefully sent a royalty through that gate at night. The guy gave order to have him punished with 50 to 100 lashes, or a club or something, and that royalty died I think.

I have seen too many animes and they get mixed up often, but I think that guy eventually became a great general in future though the anime doesn't show it.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? This is not much to go on, unless someone has already seen the anime.

Comment: @Dracor If you can recall anything else, add it to your main question body like [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/142701/edit/d7fd87d1-a3f8-421a-a72d-e91f5922076b) by editing. Please do not add details in comments as they might get overlooked.

Comment: Also, was there anything explicitly fantastical or sci-fi about this anime?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is an anime by the name [Souten Kouro](https://myanimelist.net/anime/5226/Souten_Kouro).

It follows the story of Cao Cao rising up from nothing to become a great general.

The nobles did not like him so they tried to keep him down. At some point they gave him a lowly position (gate guard commander) and he got back at them with the curfew. He also stopped most crime with this because most smugglers went through the gate at night.

Because the nobles couldn't visit their mistresses anymore, they sent a member of the royal family through the gate without informing him of the new policy. That member then threathened Cao Cao, who made sure to make an example of him. The royalty did die with Cao Cao remarking he didn't even need that many lashes.